# JavaScript event on scroll up or scroll down

Tags: javascript, scroll

Is it possible to write a JavaScript to make an action when a DIV Layer's scroll bar is manually scrolled up or scrolled down?

If so please give me a hint to implement a simple such as alert box saying you scrolled up and you scrolled down.

Comment: This should help you: http://www.adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simple use `onscroll` event of java-script.

**OnScroll Event Reference** : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_scroll.asp

Here is example,

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnScrollDiv (div) {
            var info = document.getElementById ("info");
            info.innerHTML = "Horizontal: " + div.scrollLeft
                            + "px<br/>Vertical: " + div.scrollTop + "px";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:200px;height:200px; overflow:auto;" onscroll="OnScrollDiv (this)">
        Please scroll this field!
        <div style="height:300px; width:2000px; background-color:#a08080;"></div>
        Please scroll this field!
        <div style="height:300px; width:2000px; background-color:#a08080;"></div>
        Please scroll this field!
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    Current scroll amounts:
    <div id="info"></div>
</body>
```

Working copy here : http://jsbin.com/iledat/2/edit

Comment: jQuery is not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -5):

Try [jquery scroll event](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/).

```
$('div').scroll(function(){alert('scrolled!')})
```

Comment: This won't tell you if you've gone up or down.

Comment: `-1`, jQuery is not tagged in this question.