# stop js script when scroll or click

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am using this script to make an autoscroll on my website. When the user opens the website, theres a logo and after an amount of time, the browser scrolls down.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('#logoclick').trigger('click');
    }, 3100); });
```

the problem is, that everytime the user enters the website, this script runs, which is bad, because, if the user enters the page on an anchorpoint (e.g: `mypage.com#contact`) the first thing happens is, that the browser goes to top of the page and then scrolls down.

The question is, how could I just disable the script, e.g. when the user scrolls or clicks?

Thank you!

AD

Answer (score 1):

You could put this code within an if statement which checks if an anchor is present. If so, don't execute the code.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298503/how-can-you-check-for-a-hash-in-a-url-using-javascript) for how to do that.

**EDIT**

If you also want to stop the animation when the user scrolls, even when no anchor is present, you can do so using a jQuery `stop()` function in javascripts `onScroll` event.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445945/javascript-event-on-scroll-up-or-scroll-down) for the on scroll event.
See [this](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) for the rather self-explanatory stop method.